# Laravel create relation between integer and array formed columns

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

First of all: I have no ability to change the current database columns or contents.

I have 2 different tables, `Account` and `Territory`, each represented by their models.

```
Account:
name | uid |
############
Test |   12|
Test2|   13|
Test1|  132|
Test4|  143|
```

The "uid" column is an integer

```
Territory:
###############################
name      | members            |
TestTerr  | ["12", "132", "13"]|
TestTerr2 | ["143"]            |
```

So basically the "members" column is an php array of undefined size.

Now I want to create a relationship between the two of them, unfortunately its not possible using pure sql because of the brackets `[` and `]`.

What I've tried so far:
Trying to "trick" Eloquent by saying that this is a json column -> didn't work
Trying to write my own scope, but after fiddling around I was still not able to put up a useful solution.

I think that the scope itself is not a bad idea, but I can't put the pieces together

```
    public function scopeWithBuilders(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query)
    {
        $query->addSelect(['builders' => Account::whereIn('uid', 
            function(\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $q) {
                    return $q->select(*)->from(§this->table)->where(/*get actual row??*/)->first()
        })]);
    }
```

Is there any other way how to put this relationship together?

For now I have the solution to parse every entry in the view and put everything together "by hand" but this is hell performance wise and also looks super ugly.

Comment: Which database engine do you use?

Comment: @Zhorov InnoDB on Testing and Production